# unable to Login to vesta control panel while clicking on example.com:8083

Tags: php, ubuntu, subnet, private-subnet, vesta

we are unable to login into https://example.com:8083 when we are clicking on it we getting downloaded on file and if we open the downloaded file we are getting data as
`<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/static/index.html'); ?>`
but we are opening the control panal for our website
Needed help to solve this.

This was happening when I have changes the my subnet to private from public.

Comment: Please share the response suffering a lot with this problem

Comment: The problem is php. In the correct instalation, the Apache should serve "computed PHP file", but it will not do it. There could be more types of problem.